# Unable to make Serial communication both ways

Tags: raspbian, python, serial

This is my first attempt at understanding how serial communication on pi work, so I am testing this code:

```
 '''
UART communication on Raspberry Pi using Pyhton
http://www.electronicwings.com
'''
import serial
from time import sleep

ser = serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyS0", 115200)    #Open port with baud rate
while True:
    received_data = ser.read()              #read serial port
    sleep(0.03)
    data_left = ser.inWaiting()             #check for remaining byte
    received_data += ser.read(data_left)
    print (received_data)                   #print received data
    ser.write(received_data)                #transmit data serially
```

I connected my pi ( pi 3) via usb-ttl converter to my PC ( windows). On windows I started putty and on pi I executed the above code.

It works but only in  one direction. That is I can send any data from PC to the pi, but whatever I am typing on pi is not at all appearing on PC (putty).  What can be done to make this duplex communication possible? 
[image]
**(Note: I can send serial data both ways via putty, so I understand there is no issue with serial hardware)**

**Update**

```
   ls -l /dev/ttys0
   crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 Mar 7   23:14  /dev/ttyS0    

   stty </dev/ttyS0 
   stty: 'standard input': Input/output error

   stty -F /dev/ttyS0 -a
   stty: : /dev/ttyS0  Input/output error
```

[image]

**Update 2**

[image]

Comment: Quick guess:: Putty may be expecting `/r/n` as a line terminator.  Since this is echoing, it should be there, but you might want to print out byte values for `received_data` just to check.

Comment: @goldilocks thanks for quick hint. how do we print byte values ? I am new to python.

Comment: Actually I'm not a python user, but searching "python print byte values from string" led me to https://stackoverflow.com/q/12214801/1151724 I tried that quickly and if you prefer decimal values use `"{:}"` in the join instead of `"{:02x}"`.  Check for `13:10` at the end, which is `\r\n`.

Comment: It's actually not clear how you connected it. Can you show or explain better?

Comment: @not2qubit I have put an Image this time

Comment: A couple of questions: (1) Why are you using this python script, when there are hundreds of other programs doing what you are trying to do? 
Try any of: `picocom, microcom, telnet, nc, screen` etc.  (2) What does these say: `stty </dev/ttyS0` and `ls -l /dev/ttyS0` ?

Also, your baudrate seem suspiciously low.

Comment: Perhaps, try a [working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22545/how-to-connect-to-a-serial-port-as-simple-as-using-ssh) bash script first? Then you'd know what to do with your python...

Comment: @not2qubit kindly check update

Comment: Try: `sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyS0` and `echo -e "Hello?\n\r" > /dev/ttyS0`. It's really weird that stty fails. Try this one: `stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 -a`

Comment: @not2qubit  added the screenshot of the output

Comment: Darn! I copy pasted wrong, it should be: `stty -F /dev/ttyS0 -a`.

Comment: @not2qubit stty:  /dev/ttyS0  Input/output error

Comment: On my PI3 at least, the uart port is `/dev/ttyAMA0`...

Comment: @crasic kindly see my update 2. Do you also have same mapping ?

Comment: @gpuguy Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is your problem, because the setup as described is a bit too vague. However, before using the serial devices on a Raspberry, you might (depending on your HW and OS version) need to setup your OS **and** boot config to let this happen.

Generally, you need to check/edit 3 things:

- If serial is enabled in the Kernel OS config with `raspi-config`
- Make sure nothing else is already using the serial in `/boot/config.txt`
- Disable the kernel console to use the serial in `/boot/cmdline.txt`

Do this:

```bsh
sudo raspi-config

# => Interfacing Option 
#    => Serial
#       => NO
#       => YES  <-- change to yes

sudo nano /boot/config.txt

# Add this line to disable BlueTooth (which also uses a serial line)
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt

sudo reboot

# Now edit your boot command line to prevent the linux console to
# steal control of it.
sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt

# Remove anything like these: 
#   "console=serial0,115200" or "console=ttyAMA0,115200"

sudo reboot
```